# Boggle game check spelling

Tags: c, boggle

I have made a boggle game now I want to to attach a dictionary file to it where this game check spelling and return whether the spelling is correct or wrong.

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int printRandoms(int lower, int upper,  int count);

int main()
{
    printf("\n Hello !\" Welcome to Boggle game. \" \n");
    printf(" \n Start Making as many Words as you can. \n");
    printf("\n Board number>> ");
    char arr_1[4][4]= {{'D','G','H','I'},{'K','L','P','S'},{'Y','E','U','T'},{'E','O','R','N'}};
    char arr_2[4][4]= {{'T','A','P','O'},{'E','N','E','R'},{'D','S','T','A'},{'I','G','H','C'}};
    char arr_3[4][4]= {{'E','I','L','E'},{'Z','A','B','N'},{'S','V','O','D'},{'T','E','R','A'}};
    char arr_4[4][4]= {{'H','D','E','I'},{'N','A','R','F'},{'S','O','P','U'},{'W','P','Y','L'}};
    char arr_5[4][4]= {{'F','B','L','P'},{'R','I','E','A'},{'G','M','N','D'},{'H','T','S','U'}};
    char arr_6[4][4]= {{'A','R','K','E'},{'L','O','T','N'},{'S','V','I','D'},{'P','E','B','A'}};
    char arr_7[4][4]= {{'M','A','P','O'},{'E','T','E','R'},{'D','E','N','I'},{'L','D','H','C'}};
    char arr_8[4][4]= {{'J','U','O','K'},{'A','R','K','E'},{'S','T','N','R'},{'P','E','I','T'}};
    char arr_9[4][4]= {{'G','I','L','B'},{'A','D','E','R'},{'N','V','W','S'},{'B','E','I','J'}};
    char arr_10[4][4]={{'E','R','T','E'},{'N','I','A','N'},{'S','P','F','V'},{'O','L','E','A'}};

    srand(time(NULL));   // Initialization, should only be called once.
    int number = printRandoms(1,10,1);

    printf("%c\n",number);

    switch (number) 
    {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_1[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_2[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_3[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_4[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_5[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_6[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_7[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_8[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_9[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("| %c ", arr_10[i][j]);
                }
                printf("|\n------------------\n");
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid ");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int printRandoms(int lower, int upper, int count) {
  int i;
  int num;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    num = (rand() %
      (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    printf("%d\n ", num);
  }
  return num;
}
```

This is the complete code of game I pasted. And kindly guide me how to do that I am simply learning.

Comment: Dictionary look-up is kind of a big topic. What do you need help with, more exactly? File handling? Storing a dictionary in memory? Searching through a dictionary? Try to narrow the question down.

Comment: searching through dictionary file (dictionary.txt)

Comment: Is it sorted? Do you know how to move around a file pointer? Do you know about binary search?

Comment: No, I don't know about any of that

Comment: Okay, then you need to study file handling in C (specifically `fseek`) and then basic search algorithm theory before you can write this program. Alternatively if you wish to read the whole dictionary into RAM for faster access, study hash tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "attach" a dictionary file, you have several options:

You can add a c file with a words array like this:

```
const char *words[] = {
   "banana",
   "apple",
   "baseball"
};
```

Then you need to declare this symbol in your main file like this:

```
extern const char *words[];
```

Of course you need to compile both your main file and your dictionary file together to get it working.

Another option is to write your dictionary as a raw list of words, like that:

```
banana
apple
baseball
```

And to read the file in some way from your main file. You can take a look at [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) function, it would be a good start.

With the former solution, you will be able to iterate through the dictionary with indexes, e.g. in a for loop.

With the latter, You'll only be able to read it line by line, thus reading the whole file each time you need to find a word. (You can of course read it once and store it at the beginning of your program, but you might as well use the first solution.)

Does it helps?

Comment: Can you please guide me properly by adding this code into my given code

Comment: Have you tried by yourself?